# NSTextField Autolayout when using fullscreen

Tags: macos, user-interface

i have a simpel view in my mac app:

all i want if for is to auto scale when going to full screen, using autolayout it reacts during the animation, but as soon as its full screen it snaps back to the size of the view i set in IB ( 1280 x 720 )

im using a Label ( NSTextView ) to set the text, but no mater how i set the constraints i can't get it to work.

Video [here](http://simpelapps.dk/autolayout.mov)

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this, and made  my solution  available  on git hub:

https://github.com/Skovie/ScaleNSTextField/blob/master/README.md